# What type of hardwood flooring and installation do I need for uniform look across three levels?

Tags: hardwood-floor, installation, hardwood, engineered-flooring

I am ripping out the carpet across all three levels of my house -basement, ground, and upstairs. Basement and ground are concrete slab. I want to install engineered hardwood across all three levels so the flooring looks the same. But am getting lost in the installation method choice - floating, interlocking, adhesive, and nail/staple. I assume upstairs I can nail/staple with the subfloor, but what's best for the concrete slab levels? And will I be able to find wood that works across all three levels? Thanks!

Comment: A more important consideration is if the floors are flat to a long straight edge.  They don't need to be level, but most hard flooring like planks like less than 3/16ths from flatness.  Bigger dips/ridges are not good, but might be something carpet would hide.

Comment: Floating floor type would work, with a moisture barrier in the basement

Answer (score 0):

Floating is an excellent method for use on a slab. You could use floating across all levels for consistency, or float on the concrete and nail/staple on the wood subfloor levels.

There are absolutely products which support all common installation methods. If you pick one that is appropriate to use below grade, it can be installed in the basement as well.